# Ngrx effects not waiting for required data after refactoring

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I had a working app using the original reducers, actions and effects of ngrx 7. Some of my effects read a value from the store using `withLatestFrom`, which is populated by another action/effect. They then use the `id` to load child data from an api. This has always worked as expected, the child effects wait for the parent data to be populated before executing.

```
createEffect(() => 
  this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(accountActions.loadAccountAlerts),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(fromAccount.getAccountId)),
    mergeMap(([action, id]) => //Downloads Data from Api ands dispatches a success action)
)
```

Today I refactored the reducer referenced by `fromAccount` to use createReducer using the new ngrx 8 syntax. Now suddenly my effects are no longer waiting for a value in `withLatestFrom`, they get the value of `getAccountId` as `null`.

Instead of loading data once the `accountId` is populated, all of the effects now run before the action that populates accountId is completed. I assume the way the reducer is initialized has changed, but what should I do to return to the original functionality.

Should I have ever been assuming that withLatestFrom against the store would work like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a default value in your store (BTW strongly suggest using selectors and not piping the whole store), it will be emitted, even if it is null. To ensure you have a value, use:

```js
withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(fromAccount.getAccountId).pipe(
  filter(id => !!id)
))
```

EDIT: NgRx calls the reducer first, then the effect. It sounds like you might have some other magic going on in the reducer, or perhaps this effect is reacting to the wrong action. Do you have a `loadAccountAlertsSuccss` action?

Comment: Thank you. This gave me the confidence in what I was doing to find the actual issue. In the refactoring, I had mistakenly used the same description for loadAccount, and loadAccountSuccess -> '[Account] Load Account', so it wasn't setting the accountId field in the reducer because it was running the wrong reducer path.

I actually had the line `withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromAccount.getAccountId))),` and the above was just a transposition error. Is that what you meant?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you found the issue :) it's definitely surprising the first time you come across the fact that actions are defined by their string description! As for the selector, you're better off using `this.store.select` as it lets you take advantage of memoization. If you pipe directly to the store, your Observable will emit too often. Also, if this answer was helpful, can I suggest that you mark it as the right answer so others with your problem can find it more easily?